# What kind of EM radiation best penetrate metals?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, metals

My first bet would be infrared radiation, but I have no real idea.
If the answer depends on the particular metal, let's assume we are talking about aluminium.

Comment: Side note: there are no radio waves in the infrared range

Comment: Also also wik: You should be more clear. What type of metal? Provide as many details as you can.

Comment: You can provide some more details to get precise answer.

Comment: So sorry. I changed now. Let's put aluminium for example

Answer (score 3):

A way of answering this is in terms of the [skin depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) when the electromagnetic waves can be treated classically (i.e. in the IR-microwave-radiowave region).

The skin depth of a metal to electromagnetic waves of a certain frequency is given by $d = (2/\mu_r \mu_0 \sigma \omega)^{1/2}$, where $\sigma$ is the conductivity, $\mu_r$ the relative permeability and $\omega$ the angular frequency of the radiation.

From this point of view, for a given metal, then the lower the frequency, the larger the skin depth and the further the waves penetrate into the metal.

However, you would have to get down to ELF radiowaves for the skin depth of aluminium to reach as much as 1mm. Infrared radiation would be almost entirely reflected, any penetration would be limited to a few atoms.

The "skin depth" approach is appropriate for a classical treatment of electromagnetic waves. At high frequencies, a photon nature is more appropriate.

For optical radiation, I think you know the answer. A sheet of aluminium foil easily blocks visible light. UV transmission rises, but is still easily blocked by a micron of Aluminium.

Higher energy photons may be absorbed or scattered by the photoelectric effect, Compton scattering or Pair Production. Each of these processes has its own energy dependent cross-section which depends on the metal in question. For Aluminium you can consult the [NIST tables](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ElemTab/z13.html), which give the [mass attenuation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_attenuation_coefficient) as a function of energy. For Aluminium this has a minimum at around 0.02 cm$^2$/g for X-rays/Gamma-rays of energy of around 10 MeV. For a density of 2.7 g/cm$^3$, this gives an attenuation coefficient of 0.054 cm$^{-1}$ and hence a penetration depth of 18.5 cm.

So the answer is hard X-rays.

Comment: A sheet of aluminium foil would reflect almost all infrared light and absorb the rest. @Noduagg

Comment: ok, radio waves and micro waves will do it too?

Comment: @Noduagg That is in my answer now, but perhaps I should reword it.

Comment: yes, i mean much higher frequencies than ELF radio waves, those which are used in radioastronomy

Comment: @Noduagg You don't start to get significant penetration in metals until you get to soft X-rays

Comment: @Noduagg The skin depth formula applies from about 10 micron wavelengths upwards.

Comment: I suspect, maybe through lithium even this can be much higher.